# font file with three different fonts use specific one

Tags: css, fonts

I have been provided a .ttc file that contains three different fonts:

- Futura Medium
- Futura Medium Italic
- Futura Medium Extra Bold

I want to use the Futura Medium Extra Bold in my CSS file.

I have done the following, but this just give me access to Futura Medium. Anyone know how to access the `Futura Medium Extra Bold` font?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: futuraFont;
    src: url(../fonts/Futura.ttc);
}
```

Comment: CSS `@font-face` does not support font collections, because font-face rules are for when you need to be *precise* about which single font to use when CSS uses a particular family/weight/style/variant combination. Since TTC files contain multiple font resources, that's not precision, that's ambiguity. (CSS weights are *independent* from what OpenType metadata means in OpenType font context, so there is zero reason for your CSS weight 100 to map to a collection's ultrathin, unless you *tell* the browser that's what needs to happen)

Answer (score 0):

What "Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans" is trying to suggest is, you need to convert your `ttc` file. I suggest doing a quick google search for "FontForge" and/or "FontSquirrel".